# Is it possible to run sum() aggregation in Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

[In this Cloud Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#use_the_sum_aggregation), it seems like the **sum()** aggregation is only for the client side. Is there any way I can run the **sum()** aggregation inside cloud functions using the Admin SDK?

Comment: Yeah, that should be possible. See the Node.js code sample here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#node.js_2 --- If you can't get that to work, edit your question to show the [minimal code and configuration that reproduces where you go stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That should include the relevant (minimal) package.json as the `AggregateField.sum` was only added in recent versions of the Admin SDK.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is AggregateField.sum included in the latest Admin Node.js version(11.11.0)? Because I couldn't find it in the Admin SDK document reference. Thanks

Comment: Oops... my bad. I assumed it'd be available in the Firebase Admin SDK based on that Node.js sample, but it turns out those only apply for the Google Cloud Node.js SDK for the moment. It'll be in the next major release of the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js, although I'm not sure when that'll be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

The sum() aggregation is now available in [the latest Admin SDK version](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#version_1200_-_07_december_2023) (12.0.0).

**Original**

As **@Frank van Puffelen** mentioned, the **sum()** Node.js sample in the  [Firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries?hl=en&authuser=0#use_the_sum_aggregation) is not for Firebase Admin Node.js SDK but for the Google Cloud Node.js SDK. The **sum()** aggregation is not available yet in the current Admin SDK version(11.11.0).

Comment: I have "firebase-admin": "^11.11.1", do you know if sum() has already been included?

Answer (score 2):

Inside the official documentation regarding [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin) for Node.js, you'll find an API for [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.firestore). Now, if you check the documentation related to the [CollectionReference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html) or [Query](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html), you'll see that the [count()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#count) function already exists but there is no `sum()` function present yet. I think it's a matter of time until it will be added.

Comment: Hey Andy. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of the admin SDK there's a `AggregateField` class which has the `sum()` static method as well as others like average, count,...